# AngularJS : Watch array of objects and animate the changed property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $scope collection that is continually being updated through websockets, so data is coming in about every 2 seconds.

Let's say I have this data coming in,

```
var socketData = [{
  name: 'bob',
  age: '20',
  color: 'red'
}, {
  name: 'jack',
  age: '10',
  color: 'yellow'
}]

$scope.data = socketData;
```

and it's changing constantly, like this for example, which could happen a number of seconds later.

```
var socketData = [{
  name: 'bob',
  age: '21',
  color: 'green'
}, {
  name: 'sam',
  age: '22',
  color: 'red'
}]

$scope.data = socketData;
```

and in the DOM I have this

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <p>{{d.name}}</p>
  <p>{{d.age}}</p>
  <p>{{d.color}}</p>
</div>
```

I would like to animate (by adding a class and just having it fade in) to each property that has changed.

By using $watch, I can get the changes, but only the objects as a whole.

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal) // whole object
    console.log(oldVal) // whole object
}, true);
```

So the problem is that I dont want to animate the entire object, but rather the property itself. So if the name changed for each object, in the dom I'd like to see the name fields change, not an entire object, just that individual change, and I'm having a difficult time achieving that.

Comment: what are you trying to acheive here? there is no point having watches for each property of an object. what happens there is not two but more than two objects? you will still have to watch on the array. Too many watches is a big overhead on your application and will slow down your UI updates.

Comment: Maybe `$watchCollection` instead? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection

Comment: I would like to just have one watch that can return the property that was changed.

Comment: I agree with vaibinewbee. You could create a directive that simply watched a property, and do something when it changes. It doesn't help the fact that you'd have many watches, but it could at least separate the concerns for updating the UI because of a data change

Comment: Here's an example of what I meant with a directive: http://jsfiddle.net/xGZzL/

Comment: @Ian's directive is exactly what you want. Its by far the most performant and separates the logic nicely.